# What's a good way to make a Flex component with placeholders in it?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3, mxml

I want to create a component that has a couple of "holes" that are to be filled in differently on each use.  Currently, I'm doing it like this (using the Flex 4 framework in this example --- it would look almost the same for Flex 3):

```
public var fooComponent : IVisualElement;
public var barComponent : IVisualElement;

override protected function createChildren() : void
{
  super.createChildren();

  fooContainer.addElement(fooComponent);
  barContainer.addElement(barComponent);
}

<Group id="fooContainer"/>
<!-- ... other components ... -->
<Group id="barContainer"/>
```

This works well, but it's kind of a lot of code to write for something so simple.

What I'd like is something like this:

```
[Bindable] public var fooComponent : IVisualElement;
[Bindable] public var barComponent : IVisualElement;

<Placeholder content="{fooComponent}"/>
<!-- ... other components ... -->
<Placeholder content="{barComponent}"/>
```

Now, I could implement the Placeholder component myself, but I can't help wondering if there isn't a better way to do this using the existing tools in the Flex framework.

Theoretically, with the proper compiler support, it could even be boiled down to something like this:

```
<Placeholder id="fooComponent"/>
<!-- ... other components ... -->
<Placeholder id="barComponent"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is template component practice for Flex3.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=templating_3.html

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for (I’ve read that article probably a few times already), but I doubt I’ll ever get a better one, and it is no doubt a relevant link, so I’m just going to accept this. I also realize now how poorly my question fits into StackOverflow—I was very new here when I created it, and I added the bounty probably more to try out the concept of bounties than to get an actual answer. Anyway, thanks for giving it a shot. I’m sure the link will be of use to people coming across this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

We just need to use any of standard containers as the placeholder. And we could use the addChild() and removeChild() methods to add, remove controls in that container.

Comment: Actually, I can't see where you wrote your question... I roughly understand what you want to do, but the exact kind of information you're looking for remains fuzzy for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a SkinnableComponent with a couple of SkinParts, and a proper Skin for it? I guess it could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<UIComponent id="fooComponent"/>
<!-- ... other components ... -->
<UIComponent id="barComponent"/>
```